# scala running a program never terminates

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I'm using scala 2.11.1 installed via brew, i've been using it for a while to run scripts and running REPL. now repl is working fine, but when i try to run the scala file it is not working.

```
scala scalaprogram.scala
```

The program simply contains a println("") statement. I've tried reinstalling it but didn't work yet.

it never gets terminated. what is the issue?

Comment: probably something in the code, can you show content?

Comment: it was working fine and i tried changing run config of TextMate and later i reverted it, i guess that might've caused the issue but even after reinstall it remains same.

Comment: How are you running the command? You mention TextMate  - what's the connection between that and your scala commeand? What happens if you try with a non-existent file name or a file containing syntax errors?

Comment: i tried to run it with textmate, but didn't work after i'm using shell to run it normally using scala command.

Comment: So it is working with the scala command or just not from textmate? Also please don't just say "didn't work". What did you see with TextMate? Can you try the two suggestions I made (non-existent file, file with errors)?

Comment: TextMate reports 'scala command not found' and issue i'm asking about is via shell it never gets terminated but scala command is available there in shell (and scala repl works fine).

Comment: Please try my suggestions! It would tell us more  - for instance, whether it's the compilation that's not terminating, or the execution.  FOr textmade, you've presumably not got the settings right for external commands, but I can't see it would have anything to do with scala from the shell

Comment: Yes, please post the code. Without the actual code it is almost impossible to find out what is wrong!

Comment: I saw same behaviour long back. Just wondering if this helps: http://tuxdna.in/blog/2013/02/20/scala-script-tool-seems-to-be-broken-fedora-17/